# Is it possible to use directly the linux folder /usr/include when use Visual C++ for Linux Development

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I trying to use the Visual C++ for Linux Development plugin targeting an ubuntu 16.04 VM. The connection with VM and the transfer of the local files to remote folder /home/user/projects/projectx were successful. However when I tried to add the usr/include or the usr/local/include folder to the additional include directories the relevant headers could not be resolved. I tried to use the path
$(RemoteRootDir)/../../../usr/local/include. I also tried to create symlinks of the usr/include and usr/local/include folders inside the projects folder and giving the relevant path but again the headers could not be resolved. Is this direct assignment possible or one should only use local copies of the needed linux folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of include file lookup to consider. First, when working in the Visual Studio IDE, IntelliSense will look up the headers, and definitions therin, to assist editing. In this case the files need to be on a path accessible by the Windows host. VCLinux installs generic copies of most of the header files from `/usr/include` on the Windwos host. In VS2015 they can be found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Linux\include\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\` and in VS2017 they are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\include` (change Community to Professional or Enterprise as appropriate). This is automatically  included in the predefined include path for Visual Studio.

Second, GCC (g++) needs to be able to find the headers during compilation on the Linux remote. In this case the files must be on a pth accessible by the Linux system. There is no need to add /usr/include etc. because GCC looks there by default. You can discover the default include path with

```
g++ -v -x c -E -
```

In neither case is there any reason to add `/usr/include` to the include path in your project. If IntelliSense can't find a header that should be in `/usr/include` then it might be missing. [As here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022494/linux-header-file-not-recognized-in-visual-studio-2017-linux-project/43034796#43034796).

On a more general point, you can add any path on the Linux system to the include path. GCC will find it and the headers therin and your program will compile (all other things being equal). But Visual Studio (IntelliSense) might flag an error if it can't see the same headers. Include paths can be absolute or relative although care should be take with relative paths on the Linux side because the reference point is the remote root not the project directory.

VCLinux (1.0.6) requires that include paths are specified twice, once for the Windows side and again for the Linux side. This might result in a folder that has the same path (typically relative) on both systems being duplicated.

Comment: How does this work if you're developing a library and need another project to include those headers? VCLinux doens't copy that to the include directory on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast for me when I tried doing copy and replace the full /usr/include from Linux Host to Windows (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include) it didn't work. I had to do copy and merge without replacing existing files.