# Linux header file not recognized in Visual Studio 2017 Linux Project

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When including a Linux header file, ucontext.h in this case, in a Linux C++ Project on Visual Studio 2017 for my C program, it does not recognize the header file. Even when I include sys/ucontext.h, it does not recognize functions that I should be able to use for a ucontext_t object, such as [getContext() and setContext()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getcontext.html). Shouldn't I be able to use these functions in a Linux C++ project?

Code I'm writing:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ucontext.h> 
// If I use ucontext.h instead, it gives the error: cannot open source file ucontext.h

//TCB structure
typedef struct TCB_t {
    struct TCB_t     *next;
    struct TCB_t     *prev;
    ucontext_t      context;
} TCB_t;


void init_TCB(TCB_t *tcb, void *function, void *stackP, int stack_size)
{
    memset(tcb, '\0', sizeof(TCB_t));   
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stackP;
    tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t)stack_size;

    int c = getcontext(tcb->context); // Cannot resolve field getcontext()
}
```

Comment: While you may be programming in C++ or use a C++ compiler (doesn't look like it and why then the `c` tag?) the functions and structures are still C functions and structures. There's no member functions in C, only stand-alone non-member functions in the global scope. I also suggest you read the linked reference again, and note what the functions take for *arguments*.

Comment: Ah yes, my last line was wrong and I changed that. So first, I used the c tag because this is a C program I'm writing as a VS17 Linux C++ project, as I understand that will compile as a C program after some research. Now, on the actual question I had, since there are no member functions in C, does that mean a Linux C++ project can't include C libraries in Linux? Or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: `getcontext` takes a pointer to `ucontext_t` as an argument, not a `ucontext_t` as an argument. Also since it initializes the structure you should probably change `uc_stack` after calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Linux system (Debian Jessie) `ucontext.h` is in `usr/include` which in turn includes `sys/ucontext.h` which `gcc` will find in `usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys`. The first defines the functions `getcontext` and `setcontext`. The second defines the data structures `ucontext_t` etc.

On the Windows host, VCLinux has installed a copy of the second `ucontext.h` (which defines the data structures) in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Linux\include\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\sys` . But the first `ucontext.h` is not present.

VCLinux/Visual Studio will compile and run this program on the Linux remote:

```
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   ucontext ucxt;
   ::getcontext (&ucxt);
   std::cout << ucxt.uc_flags << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

But IntelliSense will not know about the functions `getcontext` and `setcontext` or the associated data structures. So you will get little red squiggles under the names and no completion assistance.

You can take a copy of the first `ucontext.h` and put it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Linux\include\usr\include` on your Windows host. Then everything will work as it should. And you could raise an issue for the missing header on the [VCLinux GitHub site](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux).

Note: Windows paths are for Visual Studio 2015. They will be different for 2017.

Applies to VCLinux 1.0.6.

==============

Update 10-Apr-18

Microsoft have addressed the issue of differences in standard include file locations between Linux systems. As explained in [this Visual C++ blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/intellisense-for-remote-linux-headers/), the headers specific to the `GCC` setup are copied from the Linux remote and stored on the Windows host on a per-connection basis.

Comment: Yes. It compiles. It is just the IntelliSense. The folder to add your missing headers for VS 2017 is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\include\usr\include

Answer (score 5):

> On this answer to do the following you need Visual Studio Community 2017 **15.9.7+** - Tested this solution on Visual Studio Enterprise
>   2019 Preview 4.

Visual Studio needs to download all remote headers in your localmachine for correct behavior of intellisense.

New method 'rsync_ssh' doesn't download all headers. You can use old method .zip via sftp_ssh.

**0.** Add remote connection.
Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager

**1.** Select your connection
Update from Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager->Remote Headers Intellisense Manager. 
Next click on Explore button.

[image]

**2.** C:\Users[YourUser]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Linux\HeaderCache\1.0[IdNumber]
Rename the HeaderCache settings.xml.unused file to settings.xml

[image]

**3.** In the settings.xml file Change the syncMethod to sftp_ssh.

[image]

**4.** Update headers cache from Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager->Remote Headers Intellisense Manager.
**5.** Enjoy.

#### **Before**

[image]

[image]

#### **After**

[image]

[image]