# How to compile and build C++17 code with Visual studio 2017 Linux support?

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-2017, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c++17

[image: Raspberry Pi project with VS2017]

Please can someone explain how to compile and build **C++ Blink Project**(Linux/Raspberry PI Project in VS2017 15.5.5) code with -std=c++1z or -std=c++17 (g++),I have raspberry 3 model B set up and latest raspbian OS, I successfully connected and build my code and run with C++11/C++14 standard (default configured),

[image: Default standard provided]

but I want to implement C++17 features with my code such as **std::variants/optional** so on.

I think current gcc environment set up with VS2017 not supported std::c++17,I added these parameters as project C/C++ -> Command line argument,but required headers and compiler support wasn’t there.

[image: Enabling C++17/Latest support]

[image: Expected compile error]

How can I compile and build my C++17 standard code into raspbian/Raspberry Pi system using VS2017 Crossplatform(Linux) build system with external GCC/G++ compiler which supports latest standard (std=c++latest) ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you get error messages, it's always useful to show them. In full and complete and without modifications.

Comment: I want to know `how to configure this project in order to enable C++17 standard features`

Answer (score 0):

The GCC version that comes with Raspbian is outdated and doesn't fully support C++17. You need to install a newer version of the compiler.

There's various guides on the net on how to do that. [This one](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/08/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-17-programs/), for example.

Comment: I installed latest gcc on raspbian,should install gcc on windows and integrate with VS project?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga I don't know. Does VS require GCC to be installed locally in Windows too?

Comment: no they provided gcc, I think it does not support C++17,now I am trying to build with latest gcc compiler,I am kind of struggled with how to configure that with VS project.

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga If VS allows you to configure the path to the compiler on the remote (the Pi) then point it to the g++ binary in /usr/local. Basically, you need to find where you can configure the exact compiler executable that VS will use on the Pi. Also, specify "-std=c++17" manually in the command-line options of the compiler.

Comment: The real question is: do they provide/require a cross-compiler or they run some compiler straight on the Raspberry? Because the solution/setup is different...

Comment: @MatteoItalia This [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) claims VS uses the compiler on the Linux machine. It's not a cross compiler.

Comment: I installed latest gcc on raspberry Pi side,yeah want to configure VS project with that compiler.

Comment: @NikosC. I will try and let you know.Thanks guys

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga In the "Command line" options, have you tried changing "g++" to "g++-7.2.0"? Also add `-std=c++17` there (right after `-std=c++14`, so that it will override it.)  Also, have you changed the PATH environment variable as outlined in the article I linked previously, and have you rebooted your Pi after doing so?

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga If you can't figure it out, and no one has an answer, you might want to actually delete your question and open a new one (or change the current one,) asking "How do I set which Linux compiler to use in Visual Studio", or something like that.

Comment: @NikosC. I installed gcc7.20 on raspbian side already,problem is how to include those path in to VS side,currently VS using gcc/g++ path installed in windows side(installed with current VS2017).

Answer (score 0):

If you set `C++ Language Standard`to `Default` in the `C/C++ : Language` properties page (2nd screenshot) and *add* `-std=c++17` to `Additional Options` at the bottom of the `C/C++ : Command Line` page, VCLinux will add your option to the command line it sends to the Linux remote and not put in another `-std=` option of its own.
I've tried this against GCC 6.3.0 on Debian 9 (Stretch) which I believe is also the current Raspbian version. GCC 6.3 has only partial support for C++17 and it reports `__cplusplus` as `201500`, without it `__cplusplus`  is 201402 (which is C++14, the default in GCC 6.3). So the command line option is being actioned.

**9-Feb**
I take it from your comments that you are now able to compile and build C++17 code on the Linux remote.

IntelliSense runs on the Windows host and relies on the Windows compiler. For this reason it will not recognise `g++` extensions. At the time of writing, C++17 is not available as an option for VCLinux and therefore language features new to C++17 are not recognised. Presumably support will be added at some point. If you are only interested in new runtime library features then you could try bringing GCC headers onto the Windows host; this topic might be helpful in that regard [Linux header file not recognized in Visual Studio 2017 Linux Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022494/linux-header-file-not-recognized-in-visual-studio-2017-linux-project/43034796#43034796) .

Comment: Please refer these links :

Comment: I installed gcc-7.2.0 version on raspbian then set it as default gcc and switch VS2017 compiler command line to -std=c++1z  or -std=c++17
,problem VS2017 intellisense won't work for std::17 only keywords ,but VS2017 linux build system managed to compiled code with remote g++-7.2.0 on raspbian and I could able attach running process on raspbian with VS2017 using gdb server (remote debug)too.
Please refer these links :
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/08/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-17-programs/
&
https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version

Comment: For get inellisense support c++17 I tried to sync gcc-7.2.0 `include` with local(Win) directory using WinSCP tool ,and include it as VC++ includes on VS2017 but it wasn't successful.:(

WinSCP -> https://winscp.net/eng/download.php