# How to write GTK applications in Visual Studio c++ for Linux platform?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gtk, libraries

I made c++ project for Linux platform in Visual Studio and connected to linux virtual machine with `g++, gdb, gdbserver` and `libgtk-3-dev`. But I can't compile program with `gtk.h` lib. What do I need to do for Visual Studio to detect gtk?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't compile"? If you are getting an error you should post it here.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual C++ for Linux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/) builds your application on the target Linux system. Therefore the GTK+ headers and libraries need only be present on the Linux target. However, if you want IntelliSense to work (and who wouldn't) the GTK+ headers need to be visible to Visual Studio on the Windows host. The easiest way to do this is to copy the headers onto the Windows host (put them in their own folder). The include path in Visual Studio's project settings must specify the Linux path for the GTK+ headers for `g++` on the Linux target **and** the Windows path on the Windows host.

[This question might give you some more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494230/is-it-possible-to-use-directly-the-linux-folder-usr-include-when-use-visual-c/43325510#43325510)

And, as you are using c++, you might like [gtkmm](https://www.gtkmm.org/en/) which provides c++ bindings for GTK+.