# Visual Studio 2017: Is there a way to include /usr/includes in WSL on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I know 2 things in mind:

1. You can copy `/usr/includes` from WSL to Windows 10. For example, by doing `cp /usr/includes /mnt/c/`, I get `/usr/includes` folder and the contents of all POSIX C standard headers.
2. On Windows in general, you can make symbolic shortcut links to folder directories, using the CLI command, `mklink`. (See reference at bottom.)

But I wanted to know if it's possible to go even further. I want to set a C++ includes path in a C++ Makefile project (Linux Development Kit) to `/usr/includes/` in WSL for Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Is this possible?

If not, does copying the `/usr/includes` is good enough to work for Visual Studio 2017, after we include the path to the local copy directory?

And what else should you do to make this work?

References:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Yunnosch There's no XY problem here. Just asking if it's possible to add `/usr/include` to a Visual Studio 2017 project.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494230/is-it-possible-to-use-directly-the-linux-folder-usr-include-when-use-visual-c/43325510#43325510

Comment: @stanthomas But that's for VCLinux, and this is for WSL. May I ask if in both cases, the directory paths mentioned in your link above are the same?

Comment: Ok, you're going to have to explain what you're trying to do. WSL is Windows Subsystem for Linux, which is a Linux system hosted under Windows and by and large no different to a Linux system in a VM or on a seperate box. Visual Studio has an optional component - C++ for Linux development (aka VCLinux) that let's you create a Linux application on a target Linux system from the Windows hosted IDE. The Linux target can be WSL but it's still "remote" as far as VCLinux is concerned. To answer your question, the directory paths are correct up to Visual Studio Preview 15.7.3.

Comment: @stanthomas VCLinux comes with *most* POSIX C standard header files, but not all. On the other hand, WSL's `/usr/include/` directory has all POSIX C standard header files. I'm trying to map a directory from WSL to Windows 10 (or vice versa), so I can include that folder directory to `/usr/include/` in WSL to some place that Visual Studio 2017 can search/index the include files, so IntelliSense can do lookup for function names, definitions, and other things. There are certain files that only POSIX-based OSes have, because POSIX C standard files is a superset of the C standard.

Comment: Then you need to read this Visual C++ blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/intellisense-for-remote-linux-headers/

Comment: Of course, there's nothing to stop you either copying or mapping the `/usr/include` folder tree from WSL to some location visible to the Windows host, e.g. c:\WSL\myusr\include, and putting that on the include path in the project settings. It's what you'd do with any other set of header fils.

Comment: I see, I'll try those out. Thanks @stanthomas.

Comment: Now you've explained, it's probabably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022494/linux-header-file-not-recognized-in-visual-studio-2017-linux-project/43034796#43034796